# How to add viewcontrollers to my navigation controller?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I am developing an application in which I am using a `UINavigationController` in the `AppDelegate`. At launch, I initialise it with a `UIViewController`.

```
 self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];

[window addSubview:self.navigationController.view]; like this.
```

However, I would like to add other `UIViewControllers` to the `UINavigatioNController`, but I know that it isn't good practise to re-initialise the `UINavigationController` each time I would like to use the other `UIViewControllers`. Please can you tell me the normal way of doing this?

Answer (score 5):

If you know exactly what you want your stack of view controllers to be, then you can just set them directly.

For example, let's say I want the views on a navigation controller to start out as OverView > TableView > NewItemView. I want people to create their first entry as soon as they start the app. In my navigation controller I only need to do the following in `-application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`.

```
NSArray *stack = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:overViewController, tableViewController, newItemViewController, nil];
navController.viewControllers = stack;
```

Please note, this removes the old stack completely. Any view controllers in the navigation view controller will be lost.

Answer (score 2):

A UINavigationController only takes one UIViewController.

To use other UIViewControllers, they must be pushed from the rootViewController by the method:

```
- (void)pushViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
```

Documentation: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html